# How do i eliminate shaking of axes?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, properties

I'm trying to plot a solution for a 3-body problem i got using NDSolve, but for some reason y axis is shaking during the demonstration. How do i get rid of it?

```
sol = NDSolve[...];
show[t_] := Show[
  ListPlot[
   Evaluate[{
      {x1[t], y1[t]},
      {x2[t], y2[t]},
      {x3[t], y3[t]}
      } /. sol]],
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{
      {x1[T], y1[T]},
      {x2[T], y2[T]},
      {x3[T], y3[T]}
      } /. sol],
   {T, -10^-10, t}],
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ImagePadding -> 15]
Manipulate[show[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `PlotRangePadding -> None`

Comment: @Coolwater yes, that's exactly what i was looking for. thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PlotRangePadding -> None
```

Does the trick. Thanks to @Coolwater for the solution.